# @StreamListener doesn't provide an Acknowledgement header even auto-commit set to false in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement manual offset commit for the messages received on kafka. I have set the property in application.yml file but not getting Acknowldgement object from the headers

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          ens-notify-request:
            consumer:
              acknowledge-mode: manual
              autoCommitOffset: false
```

@StreamListener

```
    @StreamListener(target = INotifyRequestEventChannel.TOPIC_NAME_NOTIFY_REQUEST_EVENTS)
    public void handleEvents(Message<?> message) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Notify Request event received headers=[{}], payload=[{}]", message.getHeaders(), message.getPayload());
        try {
            Acknowledgment acknowledgment = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
            logger.info("Before handleNotifyRequest acknowledgment = {} ",acknowledgment);

        }
```

From Logs "acknowledgment = null", so unable to acknowledge event manually.

Comment: Please stop using StreamListener. It has been long deprecated along with the entire annotation-driven configuration model. All documentation for annotation support has been removed - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/

Comment: What version are you using? I just tested with your YAML and it worked as expected. `...headers={...kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(...` This is using the deprecated property `autoCommitOffset `, The other (new) property is `ack-mode` not `acknowledge-mode` https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties I used the functional consumer, but that makes no difference to the binding.

Comment: I am using spring croud version 2020.0.0 and spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.3

Comment: also I can see enable.auto.commit = true in ConsumerConfig values, so property that I am setting has no impact

Comment: That's a different property (the reason we deprecated `autoCommitOffset` is because of its similar name to the Kafka `enable.auto.commit` property). You should never set `enable.auto.commit` It does not affect whether you get an `Acknowledgment` header, but it means that manual acks will be ignored since you are deferring the commits to the `KafkaConsumer`. I am using 2020.0.4 and Boot 2.5.5.

Comment: My requirement is, we need to process one event at a time per partition. consumer should not receive second record unless and until first record is acknowledge from same partition.

Comment: @AnantBhatnagar were you able to resolve this issue? I have a similar issue, can you please help?